# Redirecting to other page after checking on connection status

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page that will be redirect to other page after 30 second.. Before it does.. It will first check for the connection status..If the connection were available then it will proceed to redirect to next page.. If connection not available then it will remain at the current page (stay)..

Problem is that after it has detected that the connection is offline then it will stay at the current page even after connection is available without refreshing the page.. How can I recheck for connection status? I mean from offline status and automatically detect the connection availability and move to next page...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        function Redirect() {
            if (Offline.state === 'up'){
                window.location = "../Offline/FPDTest.aspx";}
        }
        setTimeout('Redirect()', 30000);
</script>
```

Comment: Where does this `Offline.state` changes?

Comment: it was in js file..I did import offline.js

Comment: That library probably has your answer in it's documentaion

Comment: perhaps..but I will take years to fully understand the whole stack of javascript code i guess..but I will try later on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Muhammad Faiz, use setInterval() method. on body onload event put your function. This method calls regular interval of time. Lets say if you gave 5000 the at every 5 second it will called. Now inbetween when the connection found the next call redirect to your FPDTest.aspx page.

Refer, [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) link for more study.

For example if you have 2 page Lets say its WebForm1.aspx and WebForm2.aspx then structure of both page will be

WebForm1.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
       function Redirect() {
           console.log("hello");
            if (navigator.onLine) {
                window.location = "WebForm2.aspx";
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setInterval(function(){ Redirect();}, 5000);">

</body>
</html>
```

Webform2.aspx will be..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: here both page must have its seperate body tag if you follow my example.

You can check it by make your internet connection on/off. meanwhile make sure your localhost is running.

Comment: Thank you...I think this might be the solution.. Let me give a try first since I am not so good with this javascript things...

Comment: Sorry again Priyal... I still unclear with what I should done.. I was thinking to use setInterval(function Redirect(),31000) ..But how about the setTimeout('Redirect()',30000)? Where should i put this?

Comment: Thank you...That really make my day...Found my solution with this method... I found that this javascript really catch my interest... Might want to explore more.. Thanks again Priyal

Comment: you are welcome :) Let me know if you still need any help of mine, All the best for further development :)

Comment: Thank you again.. Can you please recommend me some site where I could learn more about javascript from the bottom? or ways to learn about javascript more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Can listen to [online/offline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) events and do whatever you need for each

```js
window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { 
  console.log('offline'); 
});

window.addEventListener('online', function(e) { 
    console.log('online'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using that library you could listen to it's `up` event

```
Offline.on("up", (ev)=> {
   window.location = "../Offline/FPDTest.aspx";
});
```

This will prevent you from calling the function unnecessarily in an interval. You can unbind the event by doing `Offline.off("up");`

You can unbind the event after 30 seconds.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
   Offline.off("up");
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Senal I would love to try solution you had gave to me.. But I cant really understand what those lines of code does.. Mind if I ask for some explanation? :( ..OMG, Seriously I need to learn a lot about javascript.. Please recommend me a website to start learning javascript from bottom..

Comment: You might have to look into arrow functions, event listeners and setTimeout method to understand the above code. There are lots of study materials you can just google it and find what is suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        function Redirect() {
            if (Offline.state === 'up'){
                window.location = "../Offline/FPDTest.aspx";}
        };

        Offline.on('up', function () {
            setTimeout(function(){ Redirect();}, 3000);
        });

</script>
```

Comment: THANKS ! I will definitely give a try to this... By the way.. What does Offline.on('up' function) do?